# How to add components to css max-width, height calculation?

Tags: html, css

I have this layout:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.r-4by3-wrap {
  max-width: calc(100vmin * 2 / 3);
  margin: auto;
}

.r-4by3 {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 150%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="r-4by3-wrap">
    <div style="border: 10px solid red">
      <div class="r-4by3" style="background: pink">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

but need to add extra bias componenet into the expressions

`calc(100vmin * 2 / 3)`
–>
`calc(100vmin * 2 / 3 + 200)`

and here

`padding-top: 150%;`
->
`padding-top: -200 * 150%;`

How could I formalize it? First is sintacticall ok, but just does something else I would expect. Second is totally wrong.

Comment: `calc(100vmin * 2 / 3 + 200)` you need a unit with 200 (ex: 200px)

Comment: which units do you need? and how both the elements are related and affected by the same amount?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share what output you expect? 
Meanwhile you can try this for max-width `calc((100vmin * 2 / 3) + 200px)`.

For padding, you can add `box-sizing: border-box;` so it doesn't add additional height to specific height. See if it helps.